# How do I make groups of 2 peaks (and one group with 1 if there's an odd number) that separates them out to different files?

Tags: python, group

So far I've written a script that can graph out data from a csv file and then identify major peaks in a graph (as well as filtering out minor peaks), which are then labeled with dots on the graph, but I am unsure how to group said peaks (as in, the dotted labels) and then isolate each group into their own csv files that cover the range of each group. How would I go about doing this?

[image: an example with a similar image I found online]

Comment: Step 1: find the positions of the peaks. Can you do that?

Answer (score -1):

you mentioned that you have already written a script to identify the major peaks and label them with dots on the graph, you can use the same script to extract the peak values and their corresponding positions.

```py
# Step 1: Identify the peaks and their positions
peaks = identify_peaks(data)  # Replace 'data' with your actual data source

# Step 2: Sort the peaks
sorted_peaks = sorted(peaks)

# Step 3: Group the peaks
groups = []
for i in range(0, len(sorted_peaks), 2):
    if i + 1 < len(sorted_peaks):
        groups.append([sorted_peaks[i], sorted_peaks[i + 1]])
    else:
        groups.append([sorted_peaks[i]])

# Step 4: Create separate files for each group
for i, group in enumerate(groups):
    with open(f"group_{i+1}.csv", "w") as file:
        for peak in group:
            file.write(f"{peak}\n")
```

In this example, the peaks list contains the identified peaks. The peaks are sorted in ascending order, and then grouped into pairs (except for the last group if there is an odd number of peaks). Each group is written to a separate CSV file named group_1.csv, group_2.csv, and so on.